# Do runs of every length occur in this string?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In reference to the strings defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/861836/16397) (constructed by repeatedly appending the last "half" of the current string), consider the particular infinite string $s$ generated by starting with $\text{abc}$:

$$\begin{align}
\quad 
&\text{abc}\\
&\text{abcbc}\\
&\text{abcbccbc}\\
&\text{abcbccbcccbc}\\
&\cdots\\
&\text{______________________________}\\
s = \ &\text{abcbccbcccbcbcccbccbcbcccbccccb...}
\end{align}
$$

More formally, the general rewriting rule is 
$$a_0 a_1 \cdots a_{n-1} \ \ \to \ \ a_0 a_1 \cdots a_{n-1} a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor } a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1} \cdots a_{n-1}.
$$
Clearly,

- $\text{a}$ occurs only in the initial position,
- $\text{b}^k$ occurs infinitely often for $k=1$, but never occurs for $k\ge2$,

and one may **conjecture** that

- $\text{c}^k$ occurs for every $k\ge 1$ (and hence, infinitely often for each $k\ge 1$).

**How to prove or disprove the conjecture?**

---

Some possibly-relevant facts:

- [Computations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35209/where-are-the-runs-in-this-infinite-string-cccccc-found) show that the index of the first occurrence of $\text{c}^k$ is as follows, for some small $k$:
  $$\begin{align}
  &\text{substring} \quad & \text{index}\\
  &\text{c} &\text{2}\\
  &\text{cc} &\text{4}\\
  &\text{ccc} &\text{7}\\
  &\text{cccc} &\text{26}\\
  &\text{ccccc} &\text{27308}\\
  &\text{cccccc} &\approx 10^{519}\\
  &\text{ccccccc} &? \ (\gt 10^{40677})\\
  \end{align}
  $$
  (The exact index for the first occurrence of $\text{c}^6$ is a $520$-digit number, and $\text{c}^7$ does not occur in the first $10^{40677}$ terms of $s$.)
- Let $L_n$  be the length of the $n$th intermediate string in the generating process illustrated above. Then 
  $$L_{n+1} = L_n + \left\lfloor\frac{L_n + 1}{2}\right\rfloor,\ \ L_0 = 3.$$
  Hence, $L_n$ grows exponentially:  $$L_n  \gtrsim 3(\frac{3}{2})^n.$$
- Let $s_n$ be the $n$th intermediate string, and let $t_n$ be the $n$th appended string (so $s_n = s_{n-1} t_n$). Now, every intermediate string *ends* with $\text{bc}$, so $\text{c}^k$ would first occur only when some $t_n$ *begins* with $\text{c}^{k-1}$, in which case $s_n= s_{n-1} t_n$ will contain the first occurrence of $\text{c}^k$ beginning at index $L_{n-1}-1$.
- After $\text{c}^k$ first occurs, the number of instances of $\text{c}^k$ grows approximately exponentially in the number of iterations, as does the length, and the ratio
  $$p_k = \frac{\text{number of instances of c}^k\text{ on the }n\text{th iteration}}{L_n} \approx \frac{1}{\text{index of the first occurrence of c}^k}
  $$
  is approximately a constant independent of $n$. 
  Since $\text{c}^{k+1}$ first occurs when one of these instances of $\text{c}^k$ happens to begin the "last half" of an intermediate string, this may be compared to a sequence of Bernoulli trials, each with success probability $p_k$. For such a process, the expected number of trials to get the first success is just $1/p_k$, so the index of the first occurrence of $\text{c}^{k+1}$ would be compared to 
  $$\frac{2}{3} L_{n_k + 1/p_k} \approx 2(\frac{3}{2})^{n_k + i_k} 
  $$
  where $n_k$ is the number of iterations to get the first occurrence of $\text{c}^k$, and $i_k$ is the corresponding index. E.g., the first-occurrence index of $\text{c}^6$ would be compared to $2(\frac{3}{2})^{n_5 + i_5} = 2(\frac{3}{2})^{22 + 27308} \approx 10^{4813}$ (when in fact it is approximately $10^{519}$). Similarly, the first-occurrence index for $\text{c}^7$ (if it exists) would be compared to $2(\frac{3}{2})^{n_6 + i_6} \approx 10^{10^{518}}$.
  These comparisons are quite poor, but may help to understand how the first-occurrence indices can be so enormous.

Comment: Your conjecture can be proved using a string based computer program. however, I am interested in seeing approach from high level mathematicians on this question :-)

Comment: Since $a$ never propagates, I imagine there's a way to state rewrite rule without it. (In which case, my point in your previous question regarding doing $abc$ v. $01$ as digits is quite superfluous.)

Comment: @Semiclassical -- The initial $\text{a}$ just acts as a "placeholder". The same sequence (without the initial $\text{a}$) is generated by starting with $\text{bc}$ and using the modified rewriting rule $a_1 \cdots a_{n} \ \ \to \ \ a_1 \cdots a_{n} a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor } a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1} \cdots a_{n}$,  but I don't see how this helps. (BTW, your reference to "my" previous question suggests that you've mistaken me for the poster of the linked question.)

Comment: Ack. Sorry for the mistaken attribution. And I don't mean that it makes things easier to prove results, just that it is superfluous either way

Comment: @Sid -- I would be interested in any algorithm/program capable of  *proving* the conjecture. (I'm skeptical that any such is available, however.)

Comment: @r.e.s. It's no proof but I've posted the problem of finding higher indices at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35209/where-are-the-runs-in-this-infinite-string. `cccccc`has not been found.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies - Thanks for the link -- the program posted there  succeeded in finding the first occurrence of $\text{c}^6$! (I edited it into the table above.)

Comment: The size of those numbers is startling. I doubt very much that anyone will be able to track down the first occurrence of $c^7$!

Comment: That lower bound on $c^7$ is kind've stupefying. I very much wish we could give an argument as to why it's so big, or some kind of heuristic for estimating it. (For instance, I note that in the computational thread you suggested that $c^6$ should occur at least 125 times before $c^7$ can appear. Can you spell out that heuristic a bit?)

Comment: @Semiclassical - After $c^k$ first occurs, more instances of it arise in two ways: (1) as copies of the original and other old copies, and (2) as new cases when an "appended half" again happens to begin with $c^{k-1}$. Now consider only the type-2 occurrences. Computations show that there is 1 occurrence of $c^2$ before $c^3$ occurs, 1 of $c^3$ before $c^4$ occurs, 4 of $c^4$ before $c^5$ occurs, 115 of $c^5$ before $c^6$ occurs, ... So far, it's a non-decreasing sequence (1, 1, 4, 115, ...). If it remains so, we should expect at least 115 $c^6$s before $c^7$ occurs. (I mistyped 115 as 125.)

Comment: Nice analysis. That suggests another problem that could be asked as a new question: What is the _distribution_ of $c^k$'s at the $N$th index? Given the Bernoulli trials model given above, one should be able to provide a statistical prediction. Numerically, of course , that's quite computationally intensive, and probably better suited for another Code Golf question (interested, @Calvin'sHobbies?)

Comment: @Semiclassical I might get around to it (or you are welcome to ask). I'm just as stupefied as you to how big those indices are.

Comment: @user1708 I've posted the same question on MO (hoping that it's still on topic over there): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177996/do-runs-of-every-length-occur-in-this-string

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to the OP of this question. Since you requested a computer program.

Below is a string based program written in Javascript that is able to calculate index of $cccc$ in your string.  [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/n5kaE/)
It does construct your string.

```
input = 'abc';
m=20;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
l = input.length;
n=(l/2);
input = input + input.substring(n, l);
}
var index=input.search(/cccc/i);
alert(index)
```

For $m=20$ it constructs a string where $cccc$ is at the index $26$,$ccc$ is at $7$,$cc$ is at $4$.

For $m=30$ it constructs a string where $ccccc$ is at the index of $27308$. (which follows your conjecture).

For $m=40$ it constructs a string, where $cccccc$ is not there and it returns $-1$, to denote that search found nothing.

Intrestingly, when I increase m to $45$, it exceeds the computational power and does not return anything on the browser (I am using chrome on win 7 64-bit). And this is because the browser storage for string as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) is about 5 MB which is a string of 2,621,440 characters.

You can however, will get success in re-writing this code in Java because it supports maximum string length of $2^{31}-1$ possibly over 2 billion as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have).

But, for that you need at least $1024 MB$ of heap size. I firmly believe your conjecture can be proved :).

Good luck!

PS: I did not had success on recreating this on Java, since I am not an expert. However, I will return to repost the solution in Java.

Comment: Your program does ***not*** prove that ($\forall k, \text{c}^k \text{ occurs in }s$), because it must be used to test **every** $k=1,2,3,...$ (infinitely many) -- a procedure that never halts. (Of course I used a similar program to compute the short table of first-occurrence indices posted in the question. On my system, using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), 47 rewrites was the maximum without memory errors.)

Comment: By switching to a system with more memory (again using Sage), I was able to extend the search to $55$ rewrites, with the result that $\text{c}^6$ does not occur in the first $17,673,600,662$ ($17^+$ billion) terms of $s$. I've updated the table.

Comment: Holy smokes! $2.124\times10^{511}$ on python!

Comment: And it renders the notion of locating $c^7$ computationally to be quite ludicrous. Heuristic arguments might get an estimate, though.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part (now fixed): the index for $\text{c}^6$ is actually $\approx 2.124\ 10^{519}$ (a $520$-digit number!). Of course, that program is doing a smarter search, and the number of positions it has to check is only a very very tiny fraction of $10^{519}$.